# AD LDS on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

Is there a way to install AD LDS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705886%28VS.85%29.aspx) on a Windows 7 machine? I can only find references to Windows Server 2008 on the net.

Comment: Does this belong on ServerFault or SuperUser?

Comment: It belongs here because LDS is geared towards developers who need an LDAP directory that cannot reside within the corporate AD DS environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, please visit [the official download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14683).